# Django: Get user's input in textarea and display them on page

Tags: python, html, django

How to get input from textarea and display them onto my webpage immediately after submit on `Django`?

Comment: The more specific you give, the more specific you get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your view add handle for POST requests and in that case render your template with template variable of your POST data.